# Get N most frequently bought combination product in one transaction using MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a data set like below:

| transaction_id | store_id | product_id | product_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | p001 | product_1 |
| 1 | 100 | p002 | product_2 |
| 1 | 100 | p003 | product_3 |
| 4 | 100 | p002 | product_2 |
| 4 | 100 | p003 | product_3 |
| 5 | 100 | p002 | product_2 |
| 5 | 100 | p003 | product_3 |
| 7 | 100 | p001 | product_1 |
| 7 | 100 | p003 | product_3 |
| 8 | 101 | p002 | product_2 |
| 8 | 101 | p003 | product_3 |
| 9 | 101 | p001 | product_1 |
| 9 | 101 | p002 | product_2 |
| 2 | 101 | p001 | product_1 |
| 3 | 101 | p002 | product_2 |
| 3 | 101 | p003 | product_3 |
| 6 | 101 | p001 | product_1 |
| 6 | 101 | p002 | product_2 |

I am trying to find a query to give output as below.

| store | freq_prod_ids | count_of_transactions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | p002, p003 | 3 |
| 100 | p001, p003 | 2 |
| 101 | p001, p002 | 2 |
| 101 | p002, p003 | 2 |

This essentially should give the top 2 [N=2] frequently bought product combinations in a single transaction for each store.

Please help to have an SQL query to get this response.

Comment: FYI, SQL Server 2008 has been completed unsupported for over 2 years; it's really past time you upgraded. If you *must* have delimited data in your resultset as well, this is harder in an unsupported version; the completely supported versions make it easy with the `STRING_AGG` function.

Comment: Do you want to group any two combinations of products? Or do you want that all products in a transaction must match another transaction in order to group it together?

Comment: Side note: your schema is denormalized. I would expect `store_id` to be in a separate `transaction` table, unless it were possible to have a single transaction with different stores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following which performs a self-join before aggregating based on store and product pairs. The [`row_number`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is used to retrieve the top 2 product pairs per store.

```sql
SELECT
    store_id, freq_prod_ids,count_of_transactions
FROM (
    SELECT
        t1.store_id,
        CONCAT(t1.product_id,', ',t2.product_id) as freq_prod_ids,
        COUNT(1) as count_of_transactions,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.store_id ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC) as rn
    FROM my_table t1 
    INNER JOIN my_table t2 on t1.store_id = t2.store_id and 
                              t1.product_id < t2.product_id and
                              t1.transaction_id = t2.transaction_id
    GROUP BY t1.store_id,CONCAT(t1.product_id,', ',t2.product_id)
) t3 WHERE rn <=2
```

[View working demo db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=3bdcaa754fc155ce80c66bba14680cc1)

Let me know if this works for you.